# Visual Studio 2012 - AnkhSVN doesn't update project to latest version if one file inside is deleted

Tags: svn, version-control, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

AnkhSVN works fine while changing code in existing classes or adding new files to project. It updates project to newest version to all members. The problem is if user deletes a file from some directory locally because he thinks he doesn't need it and then he wants to have it after all, AnkhSVN will not add that file again. So, every time when user chooses to update project to latest version, AnkhSVN will ignore that file and will not add it to project again. The only way is to delete project and open it again directly from repository.

While working with TortoiseSVN it is normal when user deletes file locally and then if he chooses to update directory to latest version, TortoiseSVN will add that file again to local version. Why is that not a case with AnkhSVN and Visual Studio 2012? Can it be fixed somehow? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Ankh calls svn delete on files deleted from the IDE:

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/156860-ann-ankhsvn-a-subversion-addin-for-visual-studio-net/

I have not found any settings to avoid it, but you can set `"Directly add new files to subversion"` in the Settings of VS as a kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

AnkhSVN will add the file again when you commit it from AnkhSVN using the pending changes or commit dialogs. AnkhSVN will (by default) not just add any file directly to your working copy as that makes it very hard to do things like fixing the casing of a file.

If you use a different client for commits (e.g. TorroiseSVN) you can use the apply to working copy command to perform the working copy commands that would otherwise be part of your commit.